# JS: Using querySelectorAll on classes that are numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select a class based on the product ID and another class, .btn-rate. I keep seem to getting an error.

`prodID = 841`

`` document.querySelectorAll(`.\\3${p.toString()[0]} + ${p.toString().substring(1)}` + ".btn-rate-positive")[0] ``

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I am escaping the numbers correctly, as far as I can tell but I think I'm appending the second class incorrectly.

Comment: what is the error? what is `p`?

Comment: Are you trying to use the first `+` as an adjacent sibling combinator, or is that your attempt at combining the two strings...? Can you simply tell us what `p` is, and what your selector *should* be?

Comment: @TylerRoper adjacent sibling

Comment: Your class really starts with a number? That causes issues which is what you are finding out.

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve]. We can't tell why it doesn't match your HTML without seeing an example of the HTML.

Comment: CSS Class & ID must start with a letter. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters